# Send file From PC to Android Device and Vice versa

Tags: java, android, tcp, network-programming, nat

I am trying to send files from PC to Android device and vice versa. My pc and Android device are connected on same network. My PC ipaddress is 192.168.1.47. After connecting my device it get Ipaddress 192.168.1.107.

Atfirst , i am opening a port(1515) of PC by this..

```
ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(1515);
Socket sock = servsock.accept();
```

Then send file from my Android Code ..

```
 Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.47", 1515);
```

And this is working fine. That means i can send file from Android device to PC.

But when i try to send file from PC to Android Devices, its not working.

Java Client code :
 Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.107", 1520);

Android server code:

```
 ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(1520);
 Socket sock = servsock.accept();
```

But this not working. After some time it shows Connection timeout exception;

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Port 1520 is known to have vulnerabilities caused by trojans and remote code execution.
Are you sure that port 1520 is open (I think it is closed by default in windows)? Have you tried with another port ?

Comment: thanks for Answer. Yes , i tried with another port.